# Which is more likely to be used in terms of KISS?

Tags: java

I have two functions. The first one:

```
public String getWeekDay(int day) {
    switch (day) {
        case 1:
            return "Monday";
        case 2:
            return "Tuesday";
        case 3:
            return "Wednesday";
        case 4:
            return "Thursday";
        case 5:
            return "Friday";
        case 6:
            return "Saturday";
        case 7:
            return "Sunday";
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("day must be in range 1 to 7");
    }
}
```

And the second one:

```
public String getWeekDay(int day) {
    if ((day < 1) || (day > 7)) throw new InvalidOperationException("day must be in range 1 to 7");
    String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    return days[day - 1];
}
```

In my opinion both are simple and do the same thing but which is better to be used when it comes to KISS principle?

Comment: I would recommend using an `enum` class for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the above, you would use an `enum` for that and these already exist within Java 8.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html

Comment: @PathisPatel uninteresting or irrelevant questions (for other people to have a similar question) are also likely to be downvoted. Here maybe "opinion asked" was maybe also a factor. Personally I think the difference in style was considered unimportant by most. BTW use `getDisplayName`

Comment: Basically what @JoopEggen wrote - especially because KISS is subjective to begin with. Frankly, I wouldn't bother too much with stuff like that, just make your code readable and try to stick to certain metrics (use Sonar Lint!) - and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using an Enum, I think it fits more to your solution

```
enum  WeekDays
{
    MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2),  //fill the rest days....

    private int day; 

    public String getDay() { 
        return this.day; 
    } 
}
```

And then check if your day exists in enum otherwise throw the exception, something like the below code

```
  for (WeekDays days : WeekDays.values()) {
        if (days.getDay() == dayToBeChecked){
            // your logic here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The second is more apt. For the newest java the **switch expression** would be nice too as it is more compact.

However better use the java time API for an English Locale.

```
/**
 * Return the weekday.
 * @param day 1=Monday till 7=Sunday (ISO standard).
 */
public String getWeekDay(int day) {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.US).format(DayOfWeek.of(day))
}
```